# Adding rows in HTML table using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to insert rows into an html table with javascript. I have the table created and can add rows successfully with the click of a button. However, I want to be able to populate the rows with elements from several arrays on load. The button is just to make sure the rows are being added.

```
<html>
 <input type="button" value="Add row" onclick="javascript:appendRow()"     class="append_row"/>
 <br/><br/></p>
 <table id="my_table" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
 <tr>
<td>Name</td>
<td>Age</td>
 <td>Sex</td>
 </tr>

</table>
<p></center></p>

 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
 function appendRow(){


var names = ["Paul", "Mike", "Linda"];
var ages = ["16", "23", "44"];
var male_female = ["M", "M", "F"];
var tbl = document.getElementById('my_table'); // table reference
// append table row
var row = tbl.insertRow(tbl.rows.length);

// insert table cells to the new row
   var row = tbl.insertRow();

for(var i=0;i<tbl.rows[0].cells.length;i++)
    createCell(row.insertCell(i), i, 'row');

 }

function createCell(cell, text, style){
var div = document.createElement('div'); // create DIV element
var txt = document.createTextNode(text); // create text node
div.appendChild(txt);                    // append text node to the DIV
div.setAttribute('class', style);        // set DIV class attribute
div.setAttribute('className', style);    // set DIV class attribute for IE (?!)
cell.appendChild(div);                   // append DIV to the table cell
}
</script>
<style>
 .row{background-color:#FFD6D6;width:43px;margin:3px;}
 .col{background-color:#D6FFD6;width:43px;margin:3px;}
  table#my_table{border-collapse:collapse;}
    table#my_table td{width:50px;height:27px;border:1px solid #D3D3D3;font-  size:10pt;text-align:center;padding:0;}
   .append_row{background-color:#FFD6D6;border:1px #ccc solid;}
   .append_column{background-color:#D6FFD6;border:1px #ccc solid;}
   .delete{background-color:#eee;border:1px #ccc solid;}
   </style>
   </html>
```

Comment: re the `setAttribute` call and IE hack: don't use `getAttribute`/`setAttribute` in an HTML document, for this reason. Better stick to the DOM Level 1 HTML properties like `div.className= style`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your for loop, try something like:

```
var j = tbl.rows.length - 1;
for (var i=0;i<tbl.rows[0].cells.length;i++) {
  var cell_text = '';
  if (i == 0) {
     cell_text = name[j];
  } else if (i == 1) {
     cell_text = ages[j];
  } else if (i == 2) {
     cell_text = male_female[j];
  }
  createCell(row.insertCell(i), cell_text, 'row');

 }
```

Comment: Seems to work for the most part. It starts with the 2nd element of the array, but does put everything where it need to be. thanks for the help.  Is there a way to make it create a number of rows based on the number of elements in the array or the length? I'm going to be using this with arrays of unknown length and need it to populate accordingly.

Comment: I guess you need j = tbl.rows.length - 2 to account for the header row. You could use an outer for loop: for (var j=0;j<name.length;j++) assuming the three arrays are the same length every time.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the "*body*" tag in the HTML syntax. You can put a call to your function in the onLoad variable, so it will be called after the page with loaded.

Comment: Yeah I left out that code for now until I see that its actually working. I'm looking for the code to put those elements in the rows.